# LibGDX - My Image isn't filling the width and height of the screen

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm having a problem getting my image to fill the whole screen without stretching itself. Currently I have an orthographic Camera set up, but the issue is the origin (0,0) of the image displays in the middle of the screen. How can I make this work? Here is the code that I have.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
   SlingshotSteve game; 

   public void Menu(SlingshotSteve game){
       this.game = game;
   }

   OrthographicCamera camera;

   SpriteBatch batch;
   TextureRegion backgroundTexture;
   Texture texture;

   GameScreen(final SlingshotSteve gam) {
        this.game = gam; 

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(800, 480);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));
    backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 500, 500);

}

public void render(float delta) {   
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      camera.update();
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, SlingshotSteve.WIDTH, SlingshotSteve.HEIGHT); 
      batch.end();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
       batch.dispose();
       texture.dispose();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your Orthographic camera implemented? It sounds like you might be interested in the "pixel-perfect" transform, which allows screen co-ordinates to correlate directly to world co-ordinates. You can use the parameters below to implement this transformation.

```
final float lOrthoLeft   = 0;
final float lOrthoRight  = pScreenHeight;
final float lOrthoTop    = 0;
final float lOrthoBottom = pScreenWidth;
final float lOrthoNear   = Float.MIN_VALUE;
final float lOrthoFar    = Float.MAX_VALUE;
```

In this regard, it is possible that your values of `lOrthoLeft`, `lOrthoRight`, `lOrthoTop` and `lOrthoBottom` of your Orthographic projection are `(-Width/2)`, `(+Width/2)`, `(-Height/2)`, `(+Height/2)` *(or some variation)* in order to position the world's origin in the centre of the screen.

However, this does also have to do with how libgdx renders to the screen. OpenGL ES, the hardware-accelerated graphical API under the hood of libgdx uses a special co-ordinate system where the centre of the screen is used as the origin. You'll find these resources useful in understanding how to work within these domains.

[libgdx co-ordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148198/libgdx-coordinate-system)

[Displaying Graphics with OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html)